# Разбор содержимого скрипта

Tags: android, python, linux, bash, qpython

На моем смартфоне установлен QPython 3. В консоли он запускается через скрипт `qpython.sh`, а вот его содержимое:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
DIR=${0%/*}
. $DIR/init.sh && $DIR/python "$@" && $DIR/end.sh
```

Все эти файлы `(qpython, init, python, end)` я перекинул в /system/xbin, так как этот путь есть в глобальных переменных. Все по-прежнему работает.

init.sh создает новые переменные для запуска бинарника в таком виде:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
export TERM=screen
export PATH=/data/data/com.hipipal.qpy3/files/bin:/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin
< и еще много много подобных строк >
```

Если в консоли набрать `init.sh && python`, то Питон выдает ошибку, загрузки разных библиотек и не, конечно же, фатальную ошибку. 
Возник вопрос, почему в случае запуска через `qpython.sh` Питон отлично видит свои переменные и по ним находит все необходимое для работы, а во втором случае нет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

потому что перед init.sh нужна точка (aka source).

```
. init.sh && python
```